# How to make webpack to produce only one file and include all chunks?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'd like to have webpack configuration, which merges everything in one file despite defined chunks. It means it should treat

```js
require.ensure(["./AsyncModule"], (require) => {
    var something = require('./AsyncModule');
});
```

the same way it treats

```js
var something = require('./AsyncModule');
```

Is there any plugin or setting for that?

Answer (score 3):

Hm, it seems that I should use

```
    new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
        maxChunks: 1
    })
```

Sorry :)